# Running timing simulation in modelsim

Tags: modelsim, quartus

I try to simulate a very very simple .vo file,the output of quartus compilation, I attached my code, .v file and quartus output .vo file.
For simulating modelsim-altera is used.
After trying for running simulation following error appeared on screen.
How can i fix this?

Thanks

CA.v :

```
module CA (input a , b, output c);
    assign c = a + b;
endmodule
```

CA.vo :

```
// Copyright (C) 1991-2014 Altera Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Your use of Altera Corporation's design tools, logic functions 
// and other software and tools, and its AMPP partner logic 
// functions, and any output files from any of the foregoing 
// (including device programming or simulation files), and any 
// associated documentation or information are expressly subject 
// to the terms and conditions of the Altera Program License 
// Subscription Agreement, the Altera Quartus II License Agreement,
// the Altera MegaCore Function License Agreement, or other 
// applicable license agreement, including, without limitation, 
// that your use is for the sole purpose of programming logic 
// devices manufactured by Altera and sold by Altera or its 
// authorized distributors.  Please refer to the applicable 
// agreement for further details.

// VENDOR "Altera"
// PROGRAM "Quartus II 64-Bit"
// VERSION "Version 14.0.0 Build 200 06/17/2014 SJ Full Version"

// DATE "12/16/2014 07:07:50"

// 
// Device: Altera EP4CE6E22C8 Package TQFP144
// 

// 
// This Verilog file should be used for ModelSim-Altera (Verilog) only
// 

`timescale 1 ps/ 1 ps

module CA (
    a,
    b,
    c);
input   a;
input   b;
output  c;

// Design Ports Information
// c    =>  Location: PIN_30,    I/O Standard: 2.5 V,    Current Strength: Default
// a    =>  Location: PIN_31,    I/O Standard: 2.5 V,    Current Strength: Default
// b    =>  Location: PIN_32,    I/O Standard: 2.5 V,    Current Strength: Default


wire gnd;
wire vcc;
wire unknown;

assign gnd = 1'b0;
assign vcc = 1'b1;
assign unknown = 1'bx;

tri1 devclrn;
tri1 devpor;
tri1 devoe;
// synopsys translate_off
initial $sdf_annotate("CA_v.sdo");
// synopsys translate_on

wire \c~output_o ;
wire \b~input_o ;
wire \a~input_o ;
wire \Add0~0_combout ;


// Location: IOOBUF_X0_Y8_N16
cycloneive_io_obuf \c~output (
    .i(\Add0~0_combout ),
    .oe(vcc),
    .seriesterminationcontrol(16'b0000000000000000),
    .devoe(devoe),
    .o(\c~output_o ),
    .obar());
// synopsys translate_off
defparam \c~output .bus_hold = "false";
defparam \c~output .open_drain_output = "false";
// synopsys translate_on

// Location: IOIBUF_X0_Y6_N15
cycloneive_io_ibuf \b~input (
    .i(b),
    .ibar(gnd),
    .o(\b~input_o ));
// synopsys translate_off
defparam \b~input .bus_hold = "false";
defparam \b~input .simulate_z_as = "z";
// synopsys translate_on

// Location: IOIBUF_X0_Y7_N1
cycloneive_io_ibuf \a~input (
    .i(a),
    .ibar(gnd),
    .o(\a~input_o ));
// synopsys translate_off
defparam \a~input .bus_hold = "false";
defparam \a~input .simulate_z_as = "z";
// synopsys translate_on

// Location: LCCOMB_X1_Y7_N0
cycloneive_lcell_comb \Add0~0 (
// Equation(s):
// \Add0~0_combout  = \b~input_o  $ (\a~input_o )

    .dataa(\b~input_o ),
    .datab(gnd),
    .datac(gnd),
    .datad(\a~input_o ),
    .cin(gnd),
    .combout(\Add0~0_combout ),
    .cout());
// synopsys translate_off
defparam \Add0~0 .lut_mask = 16'h55AA;
defparam \Add0~0 .sum_lutc_input = "datac";
// synopsys translate_on

assign c = \c~output_o ;

endmodule
```

qsim output:

```
vsim -L cycloneive work.CA
# vsim -L cycloneive work.CA 
# Loading work.CA
# ** Error: (vsim-10000) /home/bijan/Project/Quartus/CA5/simulation/modelsim/CA.vo(76): Unresolved defparam reference to '\c~output ' in \c~output .bus_hold.
#         Region: /CA
# ** Error: (vsim-10000) /home/bijan/Project/Quartus/CA5/simulation/modelsim/CA.vo(77): Unresolved defparam reference to '\c~output ' in \c~output .open_drain_output.
#         Region: /CA
# ** Error: (vsim-10000) /home/bijan/Project/Quartus/CA5/simulation/modelsim/CA.vo(86): Unresolved defparam reference to '\b~input ' in \b~input .bus_hold.
#         Region: /CA
# ** Error: (vsim-10000) /home/bijan/Project/Quartus/CA5/simulation/modelsim/CA.vo(87): Unresolved defparam reference to '\b~input ' in \b~input .simulate_z_as.
#         Region: /CA
# ** Error: (vsim-10000) /home/bijan/Project/Quartus/CA5/simulation/modelsim/CA.vo(96): Unresolved defparam reference to '\a~input ' in \a~input .bus_hold.
#         Region: /CA
# ** Error: (vsim-10000) /home/bijan/Project/Quartus/CA5/simulation/modelsim/CA.vo(97): Unresolved defparam reference to '\a~input ' in \a~input .simulate_z_as.
#         Region: /CA
# ** Error: (vsim-10000) /home/bijan/Project/Quartus/CA5/simulation/modelsim/CA.vo(113): Unresolved defparam reference to '\Add0~0 ' in \Add0~0 .lut_mask.
#         Region: /CA
# ** Error: (vsim-10000) /home/bijan/Project/Quartus/CA5/simulation/modelsim/CA.vo(114): Unresolved defparam reference to '\Add0~0 ' in \Add0~0 .sum_lutc_input.
#         Region: /CA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add library *devicename*_ver in library tab in start simulation window
be sure to use only _ver (verilog) library otherwise you see the same error